# Symlinks os via input.txt

Tags: python, r, version-control, operating-system, symlink

I use a type of repository which encodes all the paths in a input.txt
For example, my input.txt looks like
`

```
# Each line of instruction in this `inputs.txt` file should contain a destination and source delimited by a `|`.
# Lines beginning with # are ignored.
# 
# For example, suppose your `inputs.txt` file contains the following lines of text:
# > destination | source
#
# Now suppose you run the following line of code:
# > link_inputs(paths, ['inputs.txt'])
# 
# This will create a link in `paths['input_dir']` named `destination` that links to `source`.
# 
# Alternative, suppose you run the following line of code:
# > copy_inputs(paths, ['inputs.txt'])
# 
# This will create a file in `paths['input_dir']` named `destination` that is a copy of `source`.

# Destination            | Source
lib                      | {root}/lib
config.yaml              | {root}/config.yaml
final_data*              | {root}/data/output/final_data*
```

`

Then I call files in R using `source('input/lib/r/global_env.R')`

I never had any problem using this, but today I get the error. :

> Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
> cannot open the connection
> Calls: source -> file
> In addition: Warning message:
> In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
> cannot open file 'input/lib/r/global_env.R': No such file or directory
> Execution halted

I do not understand what is going on ? Why can it not read my paths from input.txt as usual ?

Comment: what is the output of `file.exists('input/lib/r/global_env.R')`?

Comment: @Marcelo Avila, it says : -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'input/lib/r/global_env.R''

Comment: Oh, I could have been a bit clearer: the file.exist() is a R command, you can pass it to your R console.